# Talkback reading extra comma in Android 12

Tags: java, kotlin, android-12, talkback, magnification

The talkback reading extra comma and text magnifcation is magnifying extra comma character even if the comma is not declared in text in Android 12
Can I get some suggestions for this query

Tried by debugging and conformed that text does not have any comma, but the accessibility is printing comma

Comment: Can you add the text excerpt which is having this issue to your question? It's hard to tell what the problem could be without being able to test it on the same data.